# Ant design select - search and filter options other than value say title or key

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a countries dropdown as given below:

```
<Form.Item>
    <Select showSearch 
        optionFilterProp="children"
        disabled={isdisabled}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => this.onDropdownChange(value)}
    >
        {Countries.map((item) => <Option
            title={item.country_name} key={item.country_name}
            id={item.alpha_2} value={item.alpha_2}>
            {item.country_name}
        </Option>)}
    </Select>
</Form.Item>
```

Now, when a user starts typing any country name then it should filter options base on anything other than value={item.alpha_2}. It could be key or title. I need value={item.alpha_2} for other things & cannot use for search.

Below are possible options for countries:

```
Countries = [
    { country_name: 'Taiwan', alpha_2: 'TW'}
    { country_name: 'Tajikistan', alpha_2: 'TJ'}
    { country_name: 'Tanzania', alpha_2: 'TZ'}
    { country_name: 'Thailand', alpha_2: 'TH'}
    { country_name: 'Timor-Leste', alpha_2: 'TL'}
    { country_name: 'Togo', alpha_2: 'TG'}
    { country_name: 'Tokelau', alpha_2: 'TK'}
    { country_name: 'Tonga', alpha_2: 'TO'}
    { country_name: 'United Arab Emirates', alpha_2: 'AE'}
    { country_name: 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland', alpha_2: 'GB'}
    { country_name: 'United States Minor Outlying Islands', alpha_2: 'UM'}
    { country_name: 'United States of America', alpha_2: 'US'}
    { country_name: 'South Africa', alpha_2: 'ZA'}
    { country_name: 'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands', alpha_2: 'GS'}
    { country_name: 'South Sudan', alpha_2: 'SS'}
]
```

Below is the retuired output when user types "united" in the select input:

[image: requred output when user types united in select input]

I tried using onSearch, onInputKeyDown, filterOption but none worked.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want exactly? when user type 'united' you want to component shows another result ?

Comment: No @barzin.A, I don't want to show another result. what I want is when user types "united" it'd show the list that matches the entered text/string & then the user can select from this list. antd already has he search feature but it works only for "value" prop. I want the search to work for key or title.

Answer (score 4):

By passing a function as a filterOption props you can handle which options should be displayed. if that function returns false the option doesn't display. this function is called for each option.

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        showSearch
        optionFilterProp="children"
        placeholder={"select a country"}
        onChange={onDropdownChange}
        filterOption={(input, option) => {
          return (
            option.key.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
            option.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
          );
          
        }}
      >
        {Countries.map((item) => (
          <Option
            title={item.country_name}
            key={item.country_name}
            id={item.alpha_2}
            value={item.alpha_2}
          >
            {item.country_name}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
```